# What's a good way to say "good preparation improves overall productivity in a long run"?

Tags: idiom-requests

In Chinese, there is a idiom that can be roughly translated to:

> Sharpening hatchets is not a waste of time for wood chopping

Is there a similar saying in English? If not, how would you express this in English?

Comment: First thing would be to get the basic English idioms right: “in **the** long run**.

Answer (score 5):

"A stitch in time saves nine." Taking care of a small matter early will save a lot of time fixing it later.

Comment: "A stitch in time saves nine" fits in terms of the meaning, but to me it seems old-fashioned.

Answer (score 3):

Measure twice, cut once.

This is in reference to wood working, sewing, activities like that.

Answer (score 0):

Preparation is half the battle.

[... is half the battle](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/half+the+battle) is a versatile idiom.

(By the way, you're thinking of 磨刀不误砍柴工, right?)

Comment: Yup. 磨刀不误砍柴工 :)

Answer (score 0):

"Take time to sharpen the saw". I have heard this used in a literal sense, and also as an encouragement to take sufficient rest so that one can perform at one's best.